# get location of Bars and restaurants using google api: android

Tags: android

i want to fetch lat , long of nearest position , bars and restaurants , i dont have any web service for getting the location coordinate, so is thee in android any way   possible to fetch  , nearest locations lat , long directly using Google api , if its possible then please let me know the way..thanks

Comment: using your mobile browser search like this https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=bars+and+restaurant

Comment: i want to access all location through my Application..

Comment: what you did for that? do you code!

Comment: i do not , just going to start..so pls suggest me right track for doing so

Answer (score 2):

Please Check the link. Here you found all information about nearest position , bars and restaurants

[Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)